# Sorting a list in python in place

Tags: python

In the function below, I need to sort "items" based on the list "rank" that is calculated within the function. But I need to do it in place and not create another object. The code below does the sorting but creates a new reference. In other words, the ids(items) before and after are different.

```
def collection_modifyitems(items):
    # calculate 'rank'
    print(id(items))
    items = [x for (y, x) in sorted(zip(test_rank, items), key=lambda s: s[0])]
    print(id(items))
```

How can I do this without creating a new reference or do it in place?

Comment: `items[:] = [x for (y, x) in sorted(zip(test_rank, items), key=lambda s: s[0])]` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `[:]` (slicing the whole list) to change the value of the old list instead of creating a new reference:

```
items[:] = [x for (y, x) in sorted(zip(test_rank, items), key=lambda s: s[0])]
```